# Problems installing DSP correction

Tags: software-installation, system, sound

I'm kind of new to this world, I'm trying to install this dsp correction since I used Equalizer APO in windows and now I'm trying to use it but with no success.
This is the rep: https://github.com/bmc0/dsp/wiki/System-Wide-DSP-Guide
I followed all the instructions but when I type this command

> pacmd load-module module-ladspa-sink sink_name=dsp master=alsa_output.pci-0000_00_14.2.analog-stereo plugin=ladspa_dsp label=ladspa_dsp.

I get this:

> Module load failed.

I really don't know what I'm doing wrong, but I'll be glad to provide more info if you want me to. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently tried to follow that guide you linked and failed as well.
The problem, as it was for me, is probably a misplaced or misconfigured config file.

You should check that you have the file named `config` (without an extension) in the right folder (/home/USER/.config/ladspa_dsp/), and create it if it's not there.
Then try running `listplugins`: at the beginning you should see something like this:

> /usr/lib/ladspa/ladspa_dsp.so:
>          ladspa_dsp (2378/ladspa_dsp)

Don't worry about the LADSPA_PATH warning, it's not important.

Next you have to check the contents of the config file. In my case, the `input_channels=2` was missing, and after fixing that everything worked.
Try to use the simplest config possible at first, e.g. the example reported in the guide.

If this doesn't work, it would be useful to have a more verbose output of the error. It can be obtained by modifying the default.pa as in the guide file and running `pulseaudio -v`.

Comment: Holy cow!, thank you so much.It was indeed the config file that was in txt. I changed it in the etc folder and then the plugin was loaded correctly. Also my speakers was the same as the demo file so no prob with the input channels. Cheers!